# Why not showing less file path in browser after running grunt in magento2?

Tags: browser, frontend, gruntjs, e-commerce, magento2

While I am running grunt, I am not able to see less file paths into the browser inspect element in magento2[click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8cvS.png)

Answer (score 1):

In magento 2.4.4 version CSS source mapping not working
Mostly for front end when working with grunt we used [devdoc](https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/frontend-core/guide/css/debug/)
but some time its not working so here is another solution for this
Edit **[Root]/package.json** file
and update the version of grunt-contrib-less to 1.4.1

```
"grunt-contrib-less": "~1.4.1"
```

then run **npm install**

that's it.
It will work for css source mapping.